# Silence all warnings in dotnet cli output

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core, dotnet-cli

I'm trying to silence all warnings in the output of the following command

```
dotnet watch run
```

I enabled a set of analyzers and there are a bit too many warnings right now. What makes this worse is that for some reason if I execute this command inside a docker container, for some weird reason I don't understand the errors are listed first and the warnings after them. So it's extremely annoying to find out what the error is when there are warnings. Especially as docker-compose is removing the color from the output, so the errors are hard to distinguish from warnings. I realize this setup is far from ideal for .NET, but it will take some time to fix this.

The warnings are shown in VS Code, they are really just noise in this command, especially as they are shown on every reload. In general I would prefer to handle the warnings only in VS Code, they are redundant in the output of this command.

I could not find any way to remove these warnings from the dotnet cli commands and keep them in VS code. Is there a way to disable all warnings in the dotnet cli commands, without affecting the display of these warnings inside VS Code?

Answer (score 3):

#### linux solution

You can use *grep* command with *--line-buffered* and *--invert-match* flags, like this:

```bash
dotnet watch run | grep --invert-match WARNING --line-buffered
```

- *--invert-match WARNING* will match every line that doesn't have *WARNINIG* in it
- *--line-buffered* enables real time output.

### windows solution

On windows with powershell you can use *[Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.3)* powershell cmdlet instead of *grep*:

```bash
dotnet watch run | Select-String -Pattern WARNINIG -NotMatch
```

- *-Pattern* - regex pattern to match
- *-NotMatch* - inverses matching, so lines that don't have *Pattern* will be matched

On windows in regular *cmd* you can use *findstr* command:

```bash
dotnet watch run | findstr /V warning
```

- *warning* - what is being matched
- */V* - inverses matching

Comment: and for windows?

Comment: thanks @johnk, I've updated my answer with solution for windows as well.