# Show error summary when build fails using dotnet run/watch

Tags: dotnet-cli

When using `dotnet run` or `dotnet watch` the errors from the build phase are intermingled with warnings. This makes it hard to spot the build error and often requires a lot of scrolling of the terminal buffer. Take for example this output:

```
/some/file/name.razor(19,44): warning CS8602: Dereference of a possibly null reference. [/some/project/path.csproj]
/some/file/name.razor(55,31): warning CS8602: Dereference of a possibly null reference. [/some/project/path.csproj]
/some/file/name.razor(61,39): error CS0023: Operator '?' cannot be applied to operand of type 'EventCallback' [/some/project/path.csproj]
/some/file/name.razor(103,63): warning CS8602: Dereference of a possibly null reference. [/some/project/path.csproj]
/some/file/name.razor(104,73): warning CS8602: Dereference of a possibly null reference. [/some/project/path.csproj]
(... numerous warnings ...)
dotnet watch ⏳ Waiting for a file to change before restarting dotnet...
```

The error is burried deep amongst numerous warnings. Trying to figure out why the build fails is way more difficult than it should be.

Whereas `dotnet build` provides a nice build summary with the error:

```
(... numerous warnings ...)
/some/file/name.razor(103,63): warning CS8602: Dereference of a possibly null reference. [/some/project/path.csproj]
/some/file/name.razor(104,73): warning CS8602: Dereference of a possibly null reference. [/some/project/path.csproj]
/some/file/name.razor(61,39): error CS0023: Operator '?' cannot be applied to operand of type 'EventCallback' [/some/project/path.csrpoj]
    212 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:26.13
```

How can I get a similar build summary when using `dotnet run` and `dotnet watch` to run my project?

Comment: You can use _grep_ to adapt output to your needs in real time, here is my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74842183/6482931) on a similar question

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of grep, however the filter needs to be adjusted for the output I've shown above. However: I still want the warnings, and grepping will also filter out some color sequences causing text to be shown in the wrong color.

Comment: Maybe redirecting _dotnet run_ output to a file and when using _tail_ on it 2 times (one with _error_ filter and one with _warning_ filter) will do the job, still won't help with color codes, and to see both outputs you'll have to use terminal multiplexer (such as _tmux_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've conditionally disabled analyzers in my build when running under `dotnet watch`. Add the following to `Directory.Build.props` and run as `DISABLE_ANALYZERS=1 dotnet watch`. As an added benefit the build will be faster as well:

```xml
<Target Name="DisableAnalyzers" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile"
        Condition="'$(DISABLE_ANALYZERS)' == '1'">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>false</RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>
        <Nullable>annotations</Nullable>
        <WarningLevel>0</WarningLevel>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```